# Bug in PHP 5.6.3 (xamp, Laravel 5) swith-case constuction?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Why function:

```
function wtf($dH)
{
    switch ($dH)
    {
        case ($dH >= 0.0 && $dH < 1.0):
            echo '$dH>=0';
            break;
        case ($dH >= 1.0 && $dH < 2.0):
            echo '$dH>=1';
            break;
        case ($dH >= 2.0 && $dH < 3.0):
            echo '$dH>=2';
            break;
        case ($dH >= 3.0 && $dH < 4.0):
            echo '$dH>=3';
            break;
        case ($dH >= 4.4 && $dH < 5.0):
            echo '$dH>=0';
            break;
        case ($dH >= 5.0 && $dH < 6.0):
            echo '$dH>=5';
            break;
        default:
            echo '$dH>=6';
            break;
    }
}
wtf(0.0);
```

after  calling it it's return:
"$dH>=1"
0.0

???

it is wrong answer because it should return first case: "$dH>=0".

???

i found this structure in: https://gist.github.com/Jadzia626/2323023

Comment: Post your entire code

Comment: I forgot write that I use Laravel 5 (and the echo-debug instruction "dd")

Comment: so its outputting `"$dH>=0" 0.0`? isnt that what youve asked it to do? It doesnt look like `dd` takes a 2nd parameter from the docs.

Comment: You can run your code here in 100+ php versions: http://3v4l.org/

Comment: I cant put my code (it not my). But it is easy to run this example. I found this construction  in: https://gist.github.com/Jadzia626/2323023

Comment: that example doesnt use `dd`, it passes the output to a variable which it then returns. Which youre not doing.

Comment: As U can see, when i change dd to echo and run in http://3v4l.org/8nr5C bug still exist:

Comment: It is because switch statements don't work like that.

Comment: EJTH - could you explain more? Where exactly is the bug?

Comment: Replace `switch ($dH)` with `switch (TRUE)` and it works.

Comment: Might also look into http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A switch statement is the same as multiple if-statements.
But... You do not need to retype the if-statement, what you're doing here.

You have 2 options for this:
-Or you check against a bool
-Or you write everything with an if

Because you already had a switch, I choose the first in this snippet:

```
private function wtf($dH)
{
    switch (true)
    {
        case ($dH >= 0.0 && $dH < 1.0):
            dd('$dH>=0', $dH);
            break;
        case ($dH >= 1.0 && $dH < 2.0):
            dd('$dH>=1', $dH);
            break;
        case ($dH >= 2.0 && $dH < 3.0):
            dd('$dH>=2', $dH);
            break;
        case ($dH >= 3.0 && $dH < 4.0):
            dd('$dH>=3', $dH);
            break;
        case ($dH >= 4.0 && $dH < 5.0):
            dd('$dH>=4', $dH);
            break;
        case ($dH >= 5.0 && $dH < 6.0):
            dd('$dH>=5', $dH);
            break;
        default:
            dd('$dH>=6', $dH);
            break;
    }
}
```

Now you will check in every `case` if the output is true, and this should work with your snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Why does this happen:

`($dH >= 1.0 && $dH < 2.0)` is evaluated to `(0.0 >= 1.0 && 0.0 < 2.0)` which is false.

This is then magically converted to 0 because of PHPs loose type comparison model.

Your switch now looks like this:

```
switch (0)
    {
        case 1 /* 0.0 >= 0.0 && 0.0 < 1.0 === true */:
            dd('$dH>=0', $dH);
            break;
        case 0:
            dd('$dH>=1', $dH);
            break;
        case 0:
            dd('$dH>=2', $dH);
            break;
        case 0:
            dd('$dH>=3', $dH);
            break;
        case 0:
            dd('$dH>=4', $dH);
            break;
        case 0:
            dd('$dH>=5', $dH);
            break;
        default:
            dd('$dH>=6', $dH);
            break;
    }
```

In other word, don't use switches like they where ifs, because they are not.

Comment: Almost: the first case will be a 1, cause that statement is true. And because of that $dH is 0, it will take the second case. And there we have the output that the OP has.

Comment: nicely explained though ;)